# Azure Web App node.js deployment failure

Tags: azure

I am trying to deploy a node.js application as Web App via git continuous deployment. The deployment fails with errors like below

```
remote: npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/isstream/-/isstream-0.1.2.tgz
remote: npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign/-/oauth-sign-0.8.2.tgz
remote: npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/stringstream/-/stringstream-0.0.5.tgz
remote: npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe/-/json-stringify-safe-5.0.1.tgz
remote: npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie/-/tough-cookie-2.3.1.tgz
```

Any one know whats causing this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a transient error due to DNS attack - not programming-related.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any systems that could be affected by the DDoS attack today? I also have had deploy errors today because of these attacks. I am using a combination of GitHub, Heroku, and Codeship, and I am sure Azure being a microsoft product / US based could also be experiencing problems.

http://www.cnbc.com/2016/10/21/major-websites-across-east-coast-knocked-out-in-apparent-ddos-attack.html

Comment: NPM has been affected: https://twitter.com/npmstatus (not that Twitter is reliable today either)

Comment: It won't even load your twitter status link :/ Man, this is a crazy day.

Comment: Ah just now saw the news regarding DDoS guys. The servers are based out of East US so I too believe this error might be because of that. Will wait and watch.

Comment: FYI - this shouldn't be posted as an answer - just as a comment. The question itself should be closed/deleted, as it's not a problem with Azure or node.js, and is not a programming question.